# iOS project - Strange characters in localized strings

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization

The localized strings are loaded with strange characters in my iOS project.
Like instead of `"Home"` it gets `"H̀o̥m̧ë"`

I set up 3 `.strings` files to store the strings used in the project and used [swiftgen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) to generate the enum for using them. (I don't know if this info is relevant, just wanted to give the most comprehensive picture.)

I have my strings like:

```
"backHomeNavButton" = "Home";
```

The code that was generated by swiftgen is:

```swift
{
…
private static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
    let format = BundleToken.bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: table)
    return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
  }
…
}

private final class BundleToken {
  static let bundle: Bundle = {
    Bundle(for: BundleToken.self)
  }()
}
```

The string is already the above mentioned result at `let format` inside `tr(_:_:_:)`

Did anyone experienced something similar?

I already tried adding a new `.strings` file, the results is the same.

I checked it in another project without swiftgen, it worked there. Then I compared those **Build Settings** that contained `Localiz` and the projects had the same settings.

I am using Xcode 12.5 at the moment, but when I opened the project in Xcode 12.4 I got the same results.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out since, so I leave the solution here if anyone gets in the same situation.

You can change the App Language in the Build Scheme. and if you set it to **Accented Pseudolanguage**, then it will produce these strange characters.